# Cocoa: hide custom scroller of textview on application startup

Tags: cocoa, scrollbar, textview, scroller

I've created a custom scroller for my textview (initiating it in the awakeFromNib method of the scrollview) and now I want to let the user chose if he wants to show the scrollbar on application startup. The problem is that the scroller always appears even if I hide it immediately after I created it and set it to be the scroller of the scrollview. The weird thing is that trying to hide the scroller after an event has been triggered (for example by clicking on a checkbox in the preferences) the scroller properly hides and shows. What I'm I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The weird thing is that before adding the custom scroller to the scrollview I have to use `setHasVerticalScroller:YES`, otherwise I can't scroll using the two-fingers scroll gesture. Then, if the user doesn't want the scrollbar to be shown I have to use `setHasVerticalScroller:NO` in the document's windowControllerDidLoadNib method, using it just after having added the scrollbar in the scrollview's `awakeFromNib` method won't work. Well, at least now it seems to work!

Comment: Only thing that has worked for me as well. When not using a nib I've been resetting to NO in the viewDidMoveToWindow method.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used IB to set up scrollbars and then used the following line if I want to suppress one of them:

```
[self.aScrollView setHasHorizontalScroller:NO]; // so only the vertical scrollbar is active
```

Try using that line in awakeFromNib, later setting it to YES if user chooses, rather than using the "hidden" property.

P.S. An NSTextView added in IB is always embedded in an NSScrollView, and it's the scrollview that governs the scrollbars. So if the above doesn't work, try calling setHasWhateverScroller on the superview of your textview:

```
[[[aTextView superview] superview] setHasHorizontalScroller:NO];
```

If you get an "unrecognized selector" error, then try explicitly casting the superview to NSScrollView (which will work only if the superview really is an instance of NSScrollView):

```
[(NSScrollView *)[[aTextView superview] superview] setHasHorizontalScroller:NO];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but this doesn't solve my problem. The problem is that after hiding the scroller using setHasVerticalScroller (yes, I'm only using the vertical scroller, I don't need the horizontal one) I can't even scroll using the trackpad, so the only way to scroll is to move the blinking cursor with the keyboard, which shouldn't happen. I think the only way to fix this is to hide the scroller, so it's still there but without being seen.

Comment: Oh, so you want scrolling via trackpad always to work, just hiding the scrollbar itself per user pref. You say it's a custom scroller, but you're initiating it in awakeFromNib, so you must be using a scrollview in a nib. You might try playing with IB settings for the scrollview, like "automatically hide scrollers." Or if you're actually not using a nib/xib, you should be using viewDidLoad, not awakeFromNib -- maybe that's the problem.

Comment: The weird thing is that before adding the custom scroller to the scrollview I have to use `setHasVerticalScroller:YES`, otherwise I can't scroll using the two-fingers scroll gesture. Then, if the user doesn't want the scrollbar to be shown I have to use `setHasVerticalScroller:NO` in the document's `windowControllerDidLoadNib` method, using it just after having added the scrollbar in the scrollview's `awakeFromNib` method won't work. Well, at least now it seems to work!

Comment: Congrats! That's not an intuitive solution, so it's especially useful. Why don't you re-post it as an answer and check it accepted so it will show up better.